# Combining content of multiple text cells into one field based on common id in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, concatenation

I need to combine the content of multiple cells into one, this is based on a common `"ID"`. I need this `"ID"` to remain after the text has been merged. I tried the `aggregate` tool but I can't get it to leave the `"ID"` field.

See the screenshot below:

[image: Example]

Comment: Is this a feature class or standalone table?

Comment: It is a standalone table. It will be joined to a larger shapefile later.

Comment: @Aaron the answer you linked does not anser the OP's question here, it's a different question

Comment: Question was closed, no answer possible. Use this expression: `concatenate(
 "long_legal_text", 
 group_by:="line_id", 
 concatenator:=','
)`

Comment: @Lukazio My apologies for closing this earlier--it is clearly different than the one I linked to.

Comment: @Babel Thanks for catching that error on my part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this expression:

```
concatenate(    
    "long_legal_text",      
    group_by:="line_id",    
    concatenator:=','  -- replace comma by any other delimiting character
)
```

[image]